# Retrieve unique elemens from an array using js

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6]

function uniqueRetriever(bla, boi) {
...
}

var unique = uniqueRetriever(bla, boi)

console.log(unique);

//output: [5, 3, 4]
```

How do I retrieve unique elements from an array without changing the original array?

Comment: What is `bla, boi` here?

Comment: Please try searching before asking

Comment: @Pointy This is not duplicate of that question. Expected output is different

Comment: @Bharadwaj, now with right dupe.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I didn't vote to close it as a duplicate; I voted to close it as "too broad" or "where's the code".

Comment: I agree with @Bharadwaj.  The OP only seems to want items that appear _once_, not _all unique values_.

Comment: @Pointy Now this is right duplicate. I can't see who is voting in which section, and your name appeared at the first so pinged you. No offence

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes I think the "close reason" is either the majority reason or the last vote reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try `filter()` like the following:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6];

var res = arr.filter(function (item, index, arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
        if(arr[i] == item)
            count++;
    }
    // check if item appears once then return item
    if(count == 1){
      return arr.indexOf(item) === index;
    }
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Bharadwaj, I have updated my answer. Thanks for correcting me.